# Module not seen in virtual environment

Tags: python

I created a virtual environment like this:

```
virtualenv venv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I installed a package in the virtual environment:

```
pip install more_itertools
```

Then I tried running a class that imports that package like this:

```
from  more_itertools import unique_everseen
```

However, I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./logpuzzle.py", line 9, in <module>
    from  more_itertools import unique_everseen
ImportError: No module named more_itertools
```

Why is that? Why is the module not seen?

Comment: What is `which pip`?

Comment: @Rishav /currentProject/venv/bin/pip. Peter No (I'm already in the virtual environment)

Comment: BTW running the virtualenv command twice is redundant, just pass in `-p` the first time. [Link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#usage)

Comment: How are you running your python file?